# Primitive roots for a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

I want to show if a number **a** is a primitive root$\pmod{n}$
Is there a way to show this without raising **a** to all the powers between **1** and **n-1**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not test all powers from $1\dots n-1:\;$  A number $a$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1\;$ is a primitive root $\bmod n\,$ iff
$$a^{\varphi(n)/q} \not \equiv 1 \pmod n$$
for every prime divisor $q$ of $\varphi(n),\,$ where $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: OK thanks. Could you show me why this method works?

Comment: See e.g Theorem 6.8 in Adler/Coury or online at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots Basically: if $a^{\varphi(n)/q} \equiv 1$ then $a$ has order smaller than $\varphi(n)$ and cannot be a primitive  root.

Comment: OK thanks for the help